# Convert numbers in a string to array in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, type-conversion

I am inputing numbers separated by commas. I need to store these numbers in an array of double elements, ignoring any other character the user has input. But the problem is that `TextBox` indices and array indices are different, and also 2.4 is stored as each separate elements.

For example, I have a string like this

```
"1,2.4,5.4,6,2"
```

How can I convert this to an array with elements

```
(1),(2.4),(5.4),(6),(2)
```

Comment: Do you need error control? Can de string be `1,2,potato,5.6,8`? Or it will be for sure correct numbers spearated by comas? Also, dou you need them on an array or a List is viable?

Comment: Yeah,It can,Thats why i need to ignore character other than numbers,But this ignore the floating point also,

Comment: I have not touch java in a while, so somoene better than me translate this into code. But just: create an array of string with the split, create a List of doubles, in a for loop iterate the string array, in each iteration try to parse to double and add it to the list.

Comment: @Aimnox : You wrote that comment the same time as I wrote an answer about exactly that :). -- Also this is VB.NET, not Java. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing the `String.Split()` function and combining that with a `For`-loop should give you the result that you want.

This will also check if it actually is a number or not, to avoid errors:

```
Public Function StringToDoubleArray(ByVal Input As String, ByVal Separators As String()) As Double()
    Dim StringArray() As String = Input.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'Split the string into substrings.
    Dim DoubleList As New List(Of Double) 'Declare a list of double values.

    For x = 0 To StringArray.Length - 1
        Dim TempVal As Double 'Declare a temporary variable which the resulting double will be put in (if the parsing succeeds).
        If Double.TryParse(StringArray(x), TempVal) = True Then 'Attempt to parse the string into a double.
            DoubleList.Add(TempVal) 'Add the parsed double to the list.
        End If
    Next

    Return DoubleList.ToArray() 'Convert the list into an array.
End Function
```

The `Separators As String()` parameter is an array of strings that the function should split your string by. Every time you call it you can initialize a new array with the separators you want (a single separator is fine).

For example:

```
StringToDoubleArray("1,2;3", New String() {",", ";"})
```

The above will split by commas (`,`) and semicolons (`;`).

**Example usage for your purpose:**

```
Dim Values As Double() = StringToDoubleArray(TextBox1.Text, New String() {","}) 'Uses a comma as the separator.
```

**Update:**

Online test: http://ideone.com/bQASvO

Comment: Thank You :) . Perfect answer

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince : Glad I could help, and thank you!

Comment: @VisualVincent - one minor critique.  You are possibly parsing the strings twice.  Instead of using Nothing in the first one, send the result to a variable and if the parse is good use that variable in the list add.

Comment: @dbasnett : Thanks for the heads-up! I was already aware of it when I wrote the answer, but I just didn't bother doing so as I was in no position to test it. Though it's not a big bottleneck unless you'd parse a **really** big array. I will rewrite the code now.

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince : I've updated the code to avoid parsing the string multiple times. Please see (I also updated the online test).

Comment: @VisualVincent - I like it.